# Getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) in swift because of PanGesture

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, syntax-error, uipangesturerecognizer

I have made a collection view with 4 cells and when you press the button in cell 1 (I have not made the other cells yet) it will take you to a new ViewController called "FirstCollectionViewController". I have a pangesturderecognizer that shows the slide out menu when you swipe in the collection view.

But when you are in the "FirstCollectionViewController" and you want to come back to the collection view, you can press a button up in the left side corner. But when I press it, I will get an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error at the "self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())" inside the ViewDidLoad in the CollectionViewController. I have tried to put the panGestureRecognizer in the ViewDidAppear but the same happens

How can i fix it?

BTW the segue which should send you back to the collection view is called: "SegueFirstCollectionViewController"

CollectionViewController :

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {


    var Array = [String]()
    var ButtonArray = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      Array =  ["1","2","3","4"]
      ButtonArray = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    }


    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Array.count
    }




    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UICollectionViewCell


        let Label = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel

        Label.text = Array[indexPath.row]

        let Button = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UIButton

        Button.setTitle(ButtonArray[indexPath.row], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
      //  Button.addTarget(self,action:#selector(ButtonArray(_:)), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)
        Button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("ButtonArray:"), forControlEvents:.TouchUpInside)

        return cell







    }
    override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        print("Inside didSelectItemAtIndexPath")
    }

        func ButtonArray(sender : UIButton) {
            print("m")


            if sender.currentTitle == "1"{
            performSegueWithIdentifier("segueFirst", sender: nil)
            }

            if sender.currentTitle == "2"{

            }
            if sender.currentTitle == "3"{

            }
            if sender.currentTitle == "4"{

            }

     } 
}
```

FirstCollectionViewController :

```
class FirstCollectionViewController : UIViewController {

    @IBAction func SegueFirstCollectionViewController(sender: UIButton) {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("SegueFirstCollectionViewController", sender: nil)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missusing segues. **Segues creates new instance of their destination ViewController**, meaning that when you start your app you have 1 CollectionViewController, then you click a cell and you have a stack of 1 CollectionViewController AND 1 FirstViewController, then you hit the button, and event it looks like it, you are not coming back to the original CollectionViewController, but you are creating a new one, meaning you now have 1 collectionViewController, one first viewController and one CollectionViewController.

This is why you are reexcecuting viewDidLoad, this is why it fail because the pan gesture recognizer has already been added to another view....

If you want to implement flat (push pop / master -> detail / back button...) you should encapsulate your collectionViewController in a NavigationViewController and use the freely given back button : **DON'T HANDLE THE BACK YOURSELF, ESPECIALLY WITH SEGUE**

*PS for the sake of beeing exact but for an advertized public : a special kind of segue exist to deal with back, they are called unwind segue. However, UINavigationController should always be the preferred option for flat navigation. Unwind segue find their use when dealing with vertical navigation (modal presentation / OK - Cancel)*

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but the thing is that when I add a navigation controller and connect it to the collection view (with Relationship ''root view controller") I will not get the button or the navigation bar when I am inside the FirstCollectionViewController (in the simulater) but when I am inside the main.storyboard i see the navigation bar but not the button.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need get the cell outside

Make set value in

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{
    //set value here
    if self.currentTitle == "1" ){
    //
    }
    else {
    //...
    }

}
```

and reload the specific cell

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(item: i, section: 0)
self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
```

Hope it would make help for you:)